# Dapper: Invalid attempt to call NextResult when reader is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dapper

I am getting the following error - sometimes - when trying to execute multiple statements using .NET 5.0, Dapper 2.0.78 with async and MSSQL Server:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call NextResult
> when reader is closed.    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryNextResult(Boolean& more)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
> Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.NextResult() in
> /*/Dapper/SqlMapper.GridReader.cs:line 414    at
> Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.ReadDeferred[T](Int32 index, Func 2
> deserializer, Type effectiveType)+System.IDisposable.Dispose()    at
> Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.ReadDeferred[T](Int32 index, Func 2
> deserializer, Type effectiveType)+MoveNext() in
> /*/Dapper/SqlMapper.GridReader.cs:line 384    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List 1..ctor(IEnumerable 1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

It does not happen all the time. I suspect the SQL connection is being closed unintentionally. What can be wrong?

To debug I have tested the SQL statements and looked at the Execution Plan in SSMS - nothing here is flagged, i.e. proper indexes, primary keys are configured, it executes in very short time.
SQL Server has

- 16 GB RAM
- SQL Server 2016 latest updates
- Intel Xeon E5-2630 v4 @ 2.2 GHz, 6 virtual processors.

Here is my code which is relatively simple.

```
private async Task<RecipeListModel> GetRecipesByIngredientAsync(int id)
    {

        string sql = @"SELECT Id,Title FROM dbo.[Ingredients] WHERE Id = @id;
                       SELECT ID,Title FROM dbo.[Recipes] WHERE IngredientId = @Id;" // simplified for the example

        RecipeListModel model = new() { };

        using (SqlConnection conn = new("my connection here"))
        {
            var data = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync(sql, new { id }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            model = new RecipeListModel
            {
                Ingredient = data.ReadAsync<Ingredient>().Result.SingleOrDefault(),
                Recipes = data.ReadAsync<Recipe>().Result.ToList()
            };
        }
        return model; // exception happens here.
    }


public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class RecipeListModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE WITH CHANGES FROM COMMENTS:**

```
    [Route("~/{lang}/ingredient/{title}-{id}", Name = "ingredient-view")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Ingredient(string title, int id, string q, int page = 1)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var model = await GetRecipesByIngredientAsync(page, id, title, q).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (model.Ingredient == null || Common.ClearUrl(model.Ingredient.Title) != title) // for SEO purposes, make sure that we do not have a tampered URL
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (model.Recipes.Any())
            {
                var total = model.Recipes.First().TotalRows;
                model.TotalRows = total;
                model.Pager = new Pager(total, page, 8);
                model.q = string.IsNullOrEmpty(q) ? "" : q.ToString();
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                RecipeListModel empty = new()
                {
                    Recipes = new List<Recipe>() { new Recipe() { Title = "" } },
                    Pager = new Pager(0, 0, 1),
                    q = q
                };
                return View(empty);
            }
        }
        return NotFound();
    }

    private async Task<RecipeListModel> GetRecipesByIngredientAsync(int p, int id, string title, string q)
    {

        string searchSql = @" -- optional (search phrase can be empty)    
                                    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE([dbo].[FT_Recipes_v], *, @SearchPhrase, LANGUAGE 'English') AS recipesFullSearch
                                    ON(r.Id = recipesFullSearch.[Key])";

        string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT Id,Title FROM dbo.[Ingredients] WHERE Id = @id;

                                ;WITH RowCounter AS (
                                SELECT COUNT(r.Id) as TotalRows
                                FROM
                                    [dbo].[Recipes] r
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[RecipeIngredients] RI ON RI.Recipe_Id = r.Id
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ingredients] I ON RI.Ingredient_Id = I.Id
                                            {0} -- inject search phrase here if not empty

                                WHERE 
                                    [Active] = 1 AND [Approved] = 1 
                                    AND I.Id = @Id
                                ),
                               
                                DataRows AS (
                                SELECT 
                                    r.Id
                                    ,STUFF( -- combine all tags into a 'csv list' like pepper[i:123]salt[i:124]...
                                            (
                                                SELECT TOP 3
                                                    ']' + Title + '[i:' + CAST(Ingredient_Id AS nvarchar(11)) [text()]
                                                FROM 
                                                    (
                                                        SELECT 
                                                            RI.Recipe_Id
                                                            ,RI.Ingredient_Id
                                                            ,I.Title
                                                        FROM dbo.RecipeIngredients AS RI
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Ingredients AS I 
                                                            ON RI.Ingredient_Id = I.Id
                                                        -- here's the relation to the main query
                                                        WHERE RI.Recipe_Id = r.Id
                                                    ) TempTable
                                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                            ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,''
                                        ) IngredientsCSV
                                ,r.Title
                                ,LEFT(r.Description,260) as Description
                                ,d.Title AS DishTypeTitle
                                ,I.Title AS IngredientTitle
                                ,RF.[file]
                            FROM
                                    [dbo].[Recipes] r
                                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[DishTypes] d ON r.DishType_Id = d.Id
                                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[RecipeIngredients] RI ON RI.Recipe_Id = r.Id
                                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ingredients] I ON RI.Ingredient_Id = I.Id
                                        {0} -- inject search phrase here if not empty
                            OUTER APPLY 
                            (SELECT TOP 1 recipe_id,[file] FROM dbo.RecipeFiles WHERE recipe_id = r.id ) RF
                            WHERE
                                    [Active] = 1 AND [Approved] = 1 AND I.[Id] = @Id
                            ORDER BY 
                                r.Id DESC
                            OFFSET (@PageNumber) ROWS 
                            FETCH FIRST (@RowsPerPage) ROWS ONLY
                        )
                            SELECT 
                                    dr.*,
                                    (select TotalRows from rowcounter) as TotalRows
                                FROM 
                                    DataRows dr;"
                            , !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q) ? searchSql : ""
                            );

        using (SqlConnection conn = new("data source=someip;initial catalog=mydb;persist security info=True;user id=u;password=p"))
        {
            using (var data = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync(sql, new
            {
                SearchPhrase = q,
                id,
                PageNumber = (p - 1) * 8,
                RowsPerPage = 8

            }).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                return new RecipeListModel
                {
                    Ingredient = await data.ReadSingleOrDefaultAsync<Ingredient>().ConfigureAwait(false),
                    Recipes = await data.ReadAsync<Recipe>().ConfigureAwait(false)
                };
            }          
        }
    }
```

Here is the full event log (notice the **NextResultAsync** instead of **NextResult** previously):

> RequestPath: /ingredient/pepper-123
>
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> Exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call
> NextResultAsync when reader is closed.    at
> Microsoft.Data.Common.ADP.ExceptionWithStackTrace(Exception e)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.NextResultAsync() in
> /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.GridReader.Async.cs:line 157    at
> Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader.ReadBufferedAsync[T](Int32 index, Func`2 deserializer) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.GridReader.Async.cs:line 241    at myproject.Controllers.HomeController.GetRecipesByIngredientAsync(Int32 p, Int32 id, String title, String q) in C:\Web\myproject\myproject-net\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 502  at myproject.Controllers.HomeController.Ingredient(String title, Int32 id, String q, Int32 page) in C:\Web\myproject\myproject-net\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 125  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilder.<>c.<b__8_0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web.Middleware.ImageSharpMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore2.WebMarkupMinMiddleware.ProcessAsync(HttpContext
> context, Boolean useMinification, Boolean useCompression)    at
> WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore2.WebMarkupMinMiddlewareBase.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
> middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

Comment: `var data` should be in a `using` block

Comment: @charlieface,  I tried your suggestion that but still I am getting these errors a few times.

Comment: Also instead of `data.ReadAsync<...>().Result` you should do `await data.ReadAsync<...>()` no `.Result`

Comment: @Charlieface I did the following but still same exceptions are thrown: 

`model = new RecipeListModel
                    {
                        Ingredient = (await data.ReadSingleOrDefaultAsync<Ingredient>().ConfigureAwait(false)),
                        Recipes = (await data.ReadAsync<Recipe>().ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList()
                    };`

Comment: Can you [edit] and show your real code for that function, as well as the object models you are using `Recipe Ingredient etc`, I suspect something else is going on, it seems you are deferring `ToList` somehow. Also can you show the rest of the stack trace

Comment: @Charlieface - I have updated the code with my changes. However, Recipe, Ingredient and RecipeListModel are as simple as I have indicated. There are only a few other properties (strings, int, datetime - nothing complex) on the models

Comment: OK given that you are not telling me all, I can only guess: one of your `.ReadAsync` doesn't have either `ToList` or `SingleOrDefault` so it is caching the IEnumerable, which is not valid after the connection is closed. You must fully enumerate the reader before you close the connection

Comment: @Charlieface - maybe I misunderstand but I have provided all information that I can. The `RecipeListModel` only contains a few other properties which are not being set by any SQL , `.ReadAsync` or similar. Those properties are a simple `Title`, a `datetime` being manually set and that is it. The funny thing is that I don't get the errors all the time - so something is telling that the statements are good but perhaps caching is taking place?

Comment: No that's not likely. Something somewhere is closing the connection. Can you confirm the following: **1.** in the SQL, the `select` statements are not bounded by `while` or `if` (so the query batch is similar to what you have put `select... from... ; select ... from... ;`)? **2.** The connection is newly created as you show, `using(SqlConnection con = new...)` and is not reused from a previous batch? **3.** There is no `Close` `CloseAsync` or `Dispose` statement anywhere, just `using` blocks? **4.** There are no special Dapper settings, no funny `Thread.Abort` or task cancellation going on?

Comment: @Charlieface - 1) Confirmed. 2) confirmed. 3) Confirmed. 4) Confirmed. I have removed `.ToList()` from `.ReadAsync` to see if that solves the problem. `.ReadAsync` already produces an `IEnumerable`. Will revert.

Comment: @Charlieface - removing `.ToList()` does not solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: I didn't think it would, if anything the opposite. You *need* to fully read each `IEnumerable` before closing the connection. What happens if instead of `.ReadSingleOrDefaultAsync()` you do `.ToList().SingleOrDefault()`?

Comment: `.ToList().SingleOrDefault()` is not a valid statement. `.ToList()` is not a valid method of `await data....`

Comment: @Charlieface - I have updated the example with full code now. This is exactly what I have.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear enough: `Ingredient = (await data.ReadAsync<Ingredient>().ConfigureAwait(false)).SingleOrDefault(), Recipes = (await data.ReadAsync<Recipe>().ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList()` does that work? The rest of your code looks correct

Comment: @Charlieface - that may actually work. I will let it run for a few hours and see. Will revert.

Comment: `.ReadAsync... SingleOrDefault()` seems to work. Feel free to post it as answer. I guess the next question would be when should I use `ReadSingleOrDefaultAsync()` if it produces exceptions from time to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but it appears to be a bug in `ReadSingleOrDefaultAsync` which causes it to close the connection.

The idea is to fully read all resultsets before you close the connection, so you need to use something that will do that. This could be `foreach`, `ToList`, `ToDictionary` or `SingleOrDefault`.

So instead use `ReadAsync` and feed it into the standard `SingleOrDefault`.

```sql
model = new RecipeListModel
{
    Ingredient = (await data.ReadAsync<Ingredient>().ConfigureAwait(false)).SingleOrDefault(),
    Recipes = (await data.ReadAsync<Recipe>().ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList(),
}
```

I hope to get a chance to debug the Dapper source code, and update this answer with exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the all the inputs. I also think it is a bug in that particular method.

Comment: A follow-up here two months later. When we remove `.ToList()` then problems start to happen again, so I guess the problem lies here. It is just that `ReadAsync` already produces an `IEnumerable` and `.ToList()` is just overhead in my opinion.

Comment: No no, you absolutely have to fully read the `IEnumerable` otherwise the reader gets disposed too early

Comment: Okay - so the `IEnumerable` is only read fully when we do `ToList`, `ToDictionary`, ..., is that correctly understood?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I said in the answer

Comment: But that's a bug, right? (or is it feature haha?)

Comment: No, that's how it supposed to work. The bug is that `ReadSingleOrDefaultAsync` doesn't seem to do that properly, it should be the equivalent of `(await ReadAsync()).SingleOrDefault`